# git produces no output when called from script via cron (log/shortlog)

Tags: linux, bash, git, cron

I've got a script `git-test` going to a local git repo and calling `git shortlog` to keep track of recent changes. For testing purposes, I just used these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /myrepo.git
result="$(/usr/bin/git shortlog -3)"
echo "$(date):$result" >> /tmp/git-log
```

the crontab entry is

```
* * * * * /home/username/git-test >> /tmp/cron-output 2>&1
```

I tried:

1. calling script from terminal -> doing fine, getting git short logs
2. calling script from cron, like above -> no git output in `/tmp/git-log` and no errors in `/tmp/cron-output`
3. calling script from cron, but doing a `$(ls -lh)"` instead of `$(/usr/bin git shortlog -3)` -> doing fine
4. calling script from cron, writing to a file directly with `git shortlog -3 >> /tmp/git-log` -> no git output in `/tmp/git-log` and no errors in `/tmp/cron-output`
5. putting the git `cd /myrepo.git;git shortlog -3 >> /tmp/cron-output 2>&1` directly in crontab -> no output and no errors in `/tmp/cron-output`

Any Ideas what the problem might be?

Thank you!

Comment: Does the cronjob at least _create_ the files in /tmp, even if empty? (Could be that you're seeing a different /tmp than cron does.) Or, if they're already created, does the cronjob have rights to write to them?

Comment: Thank you, I also tried this in various dirs including /home/user and nothing changed. But the script does create the files and prints out the $(date) from line 4 but with no results from git. Also the /tmp/cron-output gives some lines if add an extra echo or something. So the whole cronjob also does its job, when doing a simple ls -lh instead of git (s. try #3).